# Reasons to fail a build

Tags: build-process, build, continuous-integration, build-automation

As a build engineer, I'm constantly looking for new and interesting ways to improve our build process - and that includes looking for new and interesting ways to fail our builds!

I have yet to find a canonical list of reasons to fail a build ... so I figure it's time to get one created. With that in mind:

**What build-time checks - both obvious and creative - have you seen fail builds?**

Comment: Probably ;-) Wiki it is!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Compilation failure

  - Production code
  - Tests classes
- Any kind of tests failure:

  - Unit tests
  - Integration tests
  - Functional tests
  - Performance tests
- Non conformance to quality checks:

  - Coding convention (Checkstyle)
  - Test coverage (Clover, Cobertura, etc)
  - Bug patterns detection (FindBugs, PMD, Hammurapi)
  - Copy Paste detection (CPD, Symian)
  - Binary compatibility (Clirr)

Answer (score 7):

- Compilation failure
- Unit tests
- Integration tests
- System tests
- Naming conventions
- Code quality
- Regression tests

Answer (score 5):

Unapproved Checkins in Build.  Things like code checked in that is not associated to a work item or a bug fix.

Comment: +1:  Often overlooked, but very useful in a team environment where support is a daily concern.

Answer (score 2):

Unit test failure(s).

Answer (score 2):

Code failing automated quality inspections (FxCop, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

In his article introducing [Continuous Integration](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html), Martin Fowler presented [failure to run the application's suite of unit tests](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html#MakeYourBuildSelf-testing) as a compelling reason to fail a build.

Answer (score 1):

fail on compilation warning

Answer (score 1):

Introducing a cyclical dependency between modules (eg java packages).

Answer (score 1):

My company doesn't actually do this, but with a large legacy codebase like ours, it would be good to fail on undocumented changes.  Without a bug ticket of some kind, our QA department wouldn't know to test the changes, and that is scary!

Answer (score 1):

Check for duplicate classes (same package and class name) in different jar files (Java).

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as a check on compilation failure should be considered mandatory, *nuff said*.

Check-ins that lead to broken builds should be unacceptable, although the sad truth is that many organizations do accept such.

If the compilation fails:

- …you won't have a binary to use or run.
- …you can't run tests and analysis to make sure it works.
- …you can't do any other checks needed to build the project.
- …you can't please your client because you have nothing to show.

Why? **BECAUSE THE BUILD IS BROKEN**.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: I'm pretty sure I was clear about this; I mentioned ONE check and if it isn't compiling then it is **clearly not** working. I.e. `(!Compiling == !Working)` Not claiming anything else at this point because the op asked for a check. I'm pretty sure that's the obvious basics.

Comment: Edited... at least now I hope I explained it better. If you at least don't check for a compilation failure then nothing will work. Duh! :P

Answer (score 0):

Code coverage decreases or falls below an acceptable threshold.